# Delete from S first occurrence of a combination of 'red'

Tags: c++, c++builder-6

I have problems with rewriting code to Builder c++ 6 format.
So the tasks are as follows:

1. Delete from S first occurrence of a combination of 'red'
2. After first combination 'th' paste 'e'
3. Copy 5 symbols to Х from S and paste them after the 6th member(have problems with solving)
4. Delete all "." and "," from S

   ```
   void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
   {
   AnsiString S = Edit1->Text;
   AnsiString X = Edit2->Text;
   string str;

   //Delete from S first occurrence of a combination of 'red'
   str = "red";
   std::size_t pos = S.find(str);
   if(pos != std::string::npos){
       S.replace(pos, str.length(), "");
   }

   //After first combination 'th' paste 'e'
   str = "th";
   pos = S.find(str);
   if(pos != std::string::npos){
       S.insert(pos + str.length(), "e");
   }

   //Copy 5 symbols to Х from S and paste them after the 6th member
   str = 6;
   pos = S.find(str);
   if(pos != std::string::npos){
       X = S.substr(pos + str.length(), 5);
   }

   //Delete all points and comas
   for(int i=1;i<s.Length();i++){
   if(s[i]=='.')s.Delete(i,1);
   }
   for(int i=1;i<s.Length();i++){
   if(s[i]==',')s.Delete(i,1);
   }
   Label1->Caption=S;
   Label2->Caption=X;
   }
   ```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you update to a version newer than 2002. But really before that I'd work on doing away with C++ Builder all together and going to Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `AnsiString` and `std::string` logic together (or maybe you are migrating from `std::string` and do not know how to rewrite for `AnsiString`?).  `find()`, `replace()`, `insert()`, `length()`, and `substr()` are all `std::string` methods.  The `AnsiString` equivalents are `Pos()`, `Delete()`, `Insert()`, `Length()`, and `SubString()`.

There is no reason to mix the two string types together in the same function.  Pick one or the other.

Also, your two loops to delete periods/commas are broken.  You are ignoring the last character in the string, and you skip a character every time you delete a character.  So, either fix the loops, or you can just replace them with C++Builder's `StringReplace()` function instead.

If you want to re-use your existing `std::string`-based code, you can do that.  You do not have to use `AnsiString`:

```
#include <string>

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    std::string S = Edit1->Text.c_str();
    std::string X = Edit2->Text.c_str();
    std::string str;

    //Delete from S first occurrence of a combination of 'red'
    str = "red";
    std::size_t pos = S.find(str);
    if (pos != std::string::npos){
        S.replace(pos, str.length(), "");
    }

    //After first combination 'th' paste 'e'
    str = "th";
    pos = S.find(str);
    if (pos != std::string::npos){
        S.insert(pos + str.length(), "e");
    }

    //Copy 5 symbols to Х from S and paste them after the 6th member
    str = "6";
    pos = S.find(str);
    if (pos != std::string::npos){
        X = S.substr(pos + str.length(), 5);
    }

    //Delete all points and comas
    pos = S.find_first_of(".,");
    while (pos != std::string::npos) {
        s.erase(pos, 1);
        pos = S.find_first_of(".,", pos);
    }

    Label1->Caption = S.c_str();
    Label2->Caption = X.c_str();
}
```

However, since you are interacting with VCL components, it might make sense to rewrite the code to use `AnsiString` instead (or better, `System::String`, in case you ever migrate the code to a *modern* C++Builder version):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    System::String S = Edit1->Text;
    System::String X = Edit2->Text;
    System::String str;

    //Delete from S first occurrence of a combination of 'red'
    str = "red";
    int pos = S.Pos(str);
    if (pos != 0) {
        S.Delete(pos, str.Length());
    }

    //After first combination 'th' paste 'e'
    str = "th";
    pos = S.Pos(str);
    if (pos != 0) {
        S.Insert(pos + str.Length(), "e");
    }

    //Copy 5 symbols to Х from S and paste them after the 6th member
    str = 6;
    pos = S.Pos(str);
    if (pos != 0) {
        X = S.SubString(pos + str.Length(), 5);
    }

    //Delete all points and comas
    S = StringReplace(S, ".", "", TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);
    S = StringReplace(S, ",", "", TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);

    Label1->Caption = S;
    Label2->Caption = X;
}
```